# Magento redirect after moving to new host

Tags: magento, redirect

After I moved my site to new host, new domain. It still redirect to old site. For sure I set all 'web/unsecure/base_url', 'web/secure/base_url' in all scope to my new domain url. And sure that .htaccess file does not redirect to old site.

I don't know why it is redirect like that. Do you know some reasons about this? Thank you.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871159/magento-redirection-problem-after-moving

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to clear ALL CACHE! Both within Magento and on the server (like in `/path/to/magento/var/cache`)

Comment: Thanks! I cleared server cache, magento cache, browser cache and rename magento folder to another name. And it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Along with clearing your cache, I have experienced something similar, and solved it by temporarily changing the permissions on the /var folder to be writable. Then swapped it back to default after clearing again.