# Magento New Installation - Backend is working however frontend points to the old URL

Tags: magento-1.7

Tried the recommendation on several threads.  Here is the issue.  The admin is working and updated the new DB fine.  When you view the site from the frontend the product data, images, and links all point to the original site.

I Began by creating a new DB and importing a back up of the other Magento DB. The DB has a different name, the login and pw are different as well.

I modified the secure and unsecure URLs in the core_config_data table.  I then installed a fresh copy of Magento (same version as my old site ver. 1.7.0.2).

I emptied the log tables which contained the old URL as well.

I looked at the local.xml file which had the correct settings.

Please keep in mind I have not added any source files from the old site.  The olny thing that is from the old site is the DB.

Any other advice would be huge!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post links to the threads you've already tried so we don't give you repeat advice?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have followed several.  I am new to the community and did not think to log my trouble shooting.  Almost all threads suggested Changing permission on var folder,  Renaming the   core_config_data table, clearing the var/cache files, checking the local.xml file. I also purged the old URL from the log files just in case.  Any suggestions as to what I may be over looking?

Comment: Was this one of the [threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871159/magento-redirection-problem-after-moving) you looked at? If you've already fixed perms and updated your URLs in the database then I am at a bit of a loss.

Comment: It is very hard to how the new installation knows about the old URL hen I have updated it prior to importing it?  Basic facts: clean install no prior reference to the other URL AND the DB is supposedly updated properly. What else could  Magento be looking at in the DB

Comment: Short of double checking each step, I am a total loss.

Comment: Housekeeping.  I never tracked down the issue.  I simply uploaded a  fresh install and imported the data. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could get to the bottom of it.  I simply uploaded fresh install of Magento and imported the data and it worked.