# New Magento store redirecting to original store

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am trying to create a duplicate Magento store 'shopB', based on an existing implementation 'shopA'. I am doing this using a new virtual host. When I go to /skin/frontend/default/shopB/images/logo.jpg the image is there fine, so the virtual host looks to be set up ok.

I have duplicated the Magento database and updated the core_config_data for both web/secure/base_url and web/unsecure/base_url.

I have cleared var/cache, var/session and var/tmp folders.

What else should I check to stop this redirect to shopA?

Comment: Following advice from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871159/magento-redirection-problem-after-moving I checked the cache in my root directory and sure enough, Magento had been putting cache files there as I hadn't properly set permissions for my var directory. I have now cleared both caches, but still the problem persists; my shopB.com redirects to shopA.com.

Answer (score 3):

Better you delete or rename the local.xml of "shopB" and run the URL on your browser.
It will take you to installation screen. 
There you provide the duplicated "shopB"'s database name and database credentials.
After installation remove the cache.

Cheers!!

Comment: I've deleted the local.xml and tried to install again but the installation process would not proceed through to success, it kept looping through to the first step again and again.

Next I tried exporting the database and backing up my existing installation then installing Magento from fresh. This has allowed me to access the Magento back end at shopB.com/admin. However, the front end still redirects to shopA.com. 

Any ideas as to what sould be causing this issue persistently?

Answer (score 0):

Are you pointing the new test site away from the "shopA" database? /app/etc/local.xml should not have the same database settings as your original shop.

Comment: I've checked this and local.xml is pointing to the new shopB database, with the updated core_config_data urls.